# Performance tab showing very shallow stack

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I run the chrome performance tool, most of the time I get a very shallow stack shown. So it's impossible to debug anything.

It doesn't happen on my work machine but does on my home machine (also on a friends machine with the same config):

```
Windows 10 Pro - Version    10.0.18362 Build 18362
CPU ryzen 7 3700x
Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 / Beta / Canary
```

Sometimes if I use CPU throttling it shows the proper stack but the vast majority of times it does not. Am I missing a feature toggle somewhere?

Is someone else running into this?

[image: Very shallow stack]

Thank you.

Larger screenshot:
[image: Larger screenshot - same shallow stack]

Comment: Ya I can say I'm not seeing the same thing, I'd be curious how your settings are setup since I see more than one html on the left side there when I'd expect to see trees for interactions, timings, main (the file you're analyzing) then raster, gpu etc instead of another file name? The same settings which I believe would be shared between the agents for your dev profile settings which might explain why they all appear the same including edge chromium.

Comment: I'll add another screenshot with the whole panel - in this case I might have refreshed the page

Comment: I added a larger screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try using chrome stable version.

Canary is simply a much newer release that's not as well tested. I have debugged this page in my chrome (version: 78) over 10 times with 6*CPU throttling. I got stack over 10,000 ms all times.

You can get more information about performance tab in this official [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/#analyze_frames_per_second).

[image: debugged stack image]

Comment: I tried all versions of chrome - even the new Edge based on Chromium - same result